# virtualenv weird behavior: forced to use system python interpreter

Tags: python, virtualenv

EDIT: TL;DR:  I can see that my question is ambiguous. Summary of it, u can understand that whatever I do, the virtualenv keep using system python interpreter (from /usr/bin/), even if I manually specify it by `virtualenv -p`. Stranger thing is if I use `virtualenv -p python3`, it works.

Ok here's the deal
I have anaconda2, and anaconda is in PATH. Current `python`, `virtualenv`, `pip` is from anaconda2.
When I type `python`:

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

When I create new `virtualenv`, source it, `which python` does show the python interpreter from the virtualenv, but when I run `python`, something weird happended:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Upon my knowledge, `virtualenv` will use the `python` interpreter that virtualenv was installed with (`virtualenv --help` says so). That `2.7.12` python, not the same as the above python (`2.7.14`).

So I thought that "Ok maybe there is something wrong with my anaconda2's `python`. Let's use another one". I used another `python` by specifying the flag `-p` (I have many python versions installed on my machine. It's a remote server with many people accessing it, I've just pointed to one of my colleague's `python`. I can be sure there is no environment conflict here, we all use virtualenv for project and control each person's `$PATH` preferences via `~/.bash_aliases` )

No help. I start being confused. Ok maybe `virtualenv` is broken. Maybe `pip` is broken. Maybe `anaconda` is broken. Checked the path, seems tobe normal. Reinstalled everything, no help at all.

Right now, I have to use system `python` (at least it's not directly `/usr/bin/python`, but `/path/to/virtualenv/python`. At least I don't need `sudo` everywhere). Nothing much change here, but I feel so unhappy and desperately want to know the reason.
Can anyone give me a suggestion? I'll gratefully appreciated it
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very hard to understand your question. Did you use `-p` flag when creating virtualenv? What are the values `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH` variables when you have virtualenv active?

Comment: 1. Yes, I used `virtualenv -p`. 2. When not in a virtualenv: `$PATH` is `/anaconda/path/:$OTHERPATH`, when in virtualenv: `/virtual/path/:$OTHERPATH`. Everything seem tobe normal to me

Comment: I can see that my question is ambiguous. Summary of it, u can understand that whatever I do, the virtualenv keep using system `python` interpreter (from `/usr/bin/`), not the `anaconda` python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag *--always-copy* in virtualenv which helps you to copy all the files rather than using symlinking.

> --always-copy
>
> Always copy files rather than symlinking.

```
virtualenv -p python3 --always-copy python_env
```

This would mostly solve your problem.

Comment: No help at all. But if I specify `python3`, it works. This even confuses me more :(

Comment: which os are you using? try using this command _which python_ and _which python3_

Comment: Everything point to anaconda directory. I manually control the environment  by `export` command (i usually add entries to `~/.bash_aliases` for convenience). I do check `python`, `pip`, `virtualenv` and everything is normal.

Comment: if you are using linux or mac, they have preinstalled python 2.x. hence when you would type python then python 2.x would be used. Now I assume you have install python 3, so to access that you need to execute python3 command. That's why I asked you to tell the **which python**  and **which python3**  output

Comment: I have used python for more than a year and I familiar with it. In the OP I've said that if I type `python` in terminal, it will used anaconda's python. I can tell you for sure that there is nothing related to `python` version confusion here, since I control the environment quite strictly. See this screenshot. `venv` is the virtualenv name. Pay attention to 2 times I call `python`: once it's `2.7.12`, once it is `2.7.13`, when they are supposed to be identical https://imgur.com/gIYQUp8